# How to hide the url of a webapge using HTML

Tags: html, url

I want to hide the URL of a webpage using HTML. Please let me know how to do this.

I want to hide the URL as well as address bar.

Comment: ok what you have tried?

Comment: Why? Personally I'd hate any website that tried to hide things in such a way; also I'm pretty certain that outside of a 'kiosk mode' (set in the browser itself) this isn't possible.

Answer (score 0):

1st: Show us your code.
2nd: You can try and put the pages inside a frameset, and always open the pages through targeting. That way it won't show you their URL
3rd: I agree with David Thomas's opinion